# Polar coordinates in two variable function limits

Tags: calculus

Suppose that I use both $r$ and $\theta$ as variables (which means theta is not a constant it's a variable). Does switching to polar coordinates holds in any case?
For example, here [Calculating a limit in two variables by going to polar coordinates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273252/calculating-a-limit-in-two-variables-by-going-to-polar-coordinates), in the answer of Michael E2, where he considers the function  $f(x,y)=xy^2/(x^2+y^4)$, If I take $\theta = \arcsin(r \cos^2\theta)$ I can show using polar coordinates that the limit does not exist. Isn't switcing to polar coordinates equivalent to working with $x,y$? What do you think??
Thanks!
Shir

Comment: You have $\theta$ on both sides of the definition - is that intentional?

Comment: oops, sorry, you are right.. I'm just saying that what you can show with x,y you can also show with $r,\theta$. So, lets do this differently. lets take $r=cos\theta/sin^2\theta$. If we take $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ we get $r \rightarrow 0$ and can show that the limit in this case is $1/2$ which means it does not exist..

Answer (score 2):

I'm just saying that what you can show with x,y you can also show with $r,\theta$. So, lets do this differently. lets take $r=cos\theta/sin^2\theta$. If we take $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ we get $r \rightarrow 0$ and can show that the limit in this case is $1/2$ which means it does not exist..

Comment: This is why we can't say that $$\frac{r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}\to 0$$ as $r\to 0$. As far as we know \theta might be very near $Pi/2$ and then we have $f(x,y)\to 0/0$

Comment: Exactly. So, isn't its true thar working with polar coordinates is equivalent to working with x,y? isn't it's true that it is not more limited in any way? because I saw in other posts here that people tend to use them as some sort of special cases.....

Comment: Equivalent in that they give the same result.

Comment: I don't get almost anyhting of what you people are talking about: if $\,\theta \sim \pi/2\,$ ,then the above expression is $$\frac{r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}\sim\frac{r\cdot 0\cdot 1}{0+r^2}$$ . I think that what you mean is that *then*, if $\,r\to 0\,$, then we get an expression of the form $\,1/0\,$ ? Well, then you'd be right...if we hadn't that zero in the numerator!

Comment: $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ which means $\theta \neq 0$ at least thats what I ment.. and also $r=cos\theta/sin^2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that to poor $\,\theta\,$ ? We know

$$x=r\cos\theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\,\Longrightarrow $$

$$\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)}=\frac{r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}\xrightarrow[r\to 0\iff(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

The above is right for $\,\theta\ne \pi/2\;,\;3\pi/2\,$ (main angles values) (why?)

Comment: I cannot write such this fast in Latex. The final arrow's written great.

Comment: :) Note that if we put $x=t^2, y=t$ the limit is $1/2$ so this function has no limit in (0,0). I just wanted to show that we can show this if we worl with $r,\theta$ as well..

Comment: What about the $cos^{2}\theta $ in the denominator?

Comment: @jim, are you asking me? What about it?

Comment: @DonAntonio, you are saying that $$\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\to 0.$$ This limit does not exist.

Comment: No @jim, I just asked two questions: (1) Did you ask me? , and (2) What about $\,\cos^2\theta\,$ in the denominator?

Comment: Yes I asked you.

Comment: The cosine in the denominator means that we cannot be sure that the limit is zero. In fact the limit does not exist.

Comment: I asked the question about cosine in the denominator because I thought that you were not right in this instance to conclude that the limit is zero. That was all I was trying to point out.

Comment: Indeed I wasn't: precisely on the angle $\,\pi/2\,$ we've a problem. I gather this from all the other comments in other answers ,no t from here. Nice problem to show that passing to other coordinates can sometimes "hide" problems that are clearer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can say that the expression goes to zero, independent of $\theta$, along any ray of constant $\theta$.  The expression is equal to

$$\frac{r \cos{\theta} \sin^2{\theta}}{\cos^2{\theta} + r^2 \sin^4{\theta}}$$

Even when $\theta = \pi/2$, the expression still goes to zero because of the cosine in the numerator.  The question is, does it go to zero uniformly as $r \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Note that if we put $x=t^2, y=t$ the limit is $1/2$ so this function has no limit in (0,0). I just wanted to show that we can show this if we worl with $r,\theta$ as well..

Comment: OK, but that is a different limit altogether.  When you use polars, you are weighting $x$ and $y$ the same.  In this special case, you are not.

Comment: Why not? They are two independent variables arn't they? don't we use them here exactly in the same way as we use them in polar representation of a complex number for instance?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are independent, but when you introduce polars, you assign equal weight to them.  That's the whole point of a Jacobian, for example.  If you want to show that a limit doesn't exist on some curve, as you do, then that is different from assigning $x$ and $y$ polar coordinates in the usual sense.

Comment: I can't see why you claim that the cosine in the numerator means that for $\theta=\pi/2$ the limit is $0$. It is surely the cosine in the denominator that should make us pause.

Comment: Because $\cos{\pi/2}=0$, full stop.  Thus the limit is zero by definition of a limit. $r \ne 0$.

Comment: A limit if it exists is unique.

Comment: You have $cos^{2}\theta$ in the denominator.

Comment: So what?  $r \ne 0$, because you are taking a limit.

Comment: Ok sure that's if $\theta=\pi/2$ but we don't know the behaviour of     $\theta$. It could be approaching $\pi/2$.

Comment: In that case, $\sec{\theta}$ is finite, and now $r \rightarrow 0$.  And I am not sure about $\theta$ approaching anything - the limit is an approach toward the origin.  Look, if you want to approach the origin on a spiral or something like that, fine.  But in that case, I have no idea what the OP's question is.

Comment: Precisely, it could be a spiral, or anything. We know nothing about $\theta$. My point is that this limit does not exist. If switching to polar coordinates is a method for evaluating limits, our usage of them shouldn't tell us a limit exists when it doesn't.

Comment: Then there's no point in switching to polars - you can define any parametric curve in $x$ and $y$, as the OP showed above.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wouldn't use polar coordinates here. I would use them to get everything dodgy out of a denominator like $x^{2}+y^{2}.$ Here, I would do what you are saying and let $x=\alpha y^{2}$.

Comment: I wouldn't use them as well un this case. But that wasn't my point. My point was that, switching to polar coordinates is global. which means that if we work with them carefully then, if the limit exists we can proof it and if not we can show it. Exactly the same as when we work with x,y..