# Continuous function bounded on each line is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a **continuous** function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ bounded on each line passing through the origin. Is this function bounded near the origin?

Ps: you can assume $f$ is smooth if you want.

Comment: Being smooth is not a requirement, just optional, but being contunuous is a requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^8}.$$
This function is continuous and for the limit on each line is bounded, as for $y=ax$ one has
$$f(x,ax)=\frac{a^3x^5}{x^4+a^8x^8}$$
which goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$. The same applies to the vertical line $x=0$.

Nonetheless, this function diverges along the curve $x=y^2$ as there the function is
$$f(y^2,y)=\frac{y^7}{y^8+y^8}=\frac{1}{2y},$$
which clearly diverges

This answer took inspiration from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/274879/119285

Comment: This function is not continuous...

Comment: Here is an example. I took inspiration from another question.

Comment: If I wanted to guarantee f is bounded, what kind of curves I would have to analyze?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. If you check "all" of course it works, but that's surely not of big help